# Bounded MPMC queue with semaphore

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, queue, semaphore

I have founded a very excellent Bounded MPMC queue source in

http://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/queues/bounded-mpmc-queue

and the test is quite easy :

```
mpmc_bounded_queue<string> mq(8) ;

for(int idx=0;idx<10;idx++)
{
    string s = to_string(idx);
    if(mq.enqueue(s))
        cout << s << " ok" << endl ;
    else
        cout << s << " not ok" << endl ;
}

string strx;    
if(mq.dequeue(strx))
{
    cout << "The dequeue value=" << strx << endl ;
}else{
    assert(1 == 2) ;
}

string s = "THE END" ;
if(mq.enqueue(s))
    cout << s << " ok" << endl ;
else
    cout << s << " not ok" << endl ;
```

After I study this code , I like to make sure if I can use this source correctly ,
Suppose there is one thread C waiting for a semaphore , after awaked (semaphore >0), 
thread C will call dequeue function to get the data from queue !!  thread A and thread B 
will call enqueue function , after inserting one data , semaphore + 1 , so if thread A and 
thread B enqueue to queue 10 times , semaphore would be 10 , then thread C should be able to dequeue 10 times , that should works perfect so far !!!

But one thing I think might happen ! ... Suppose thread A and thread B do enqueue at the 
very same time , after Compare-And-Swap , thread A should fill buffer[0] and thread B 
should fill buffer[1] , thread A not finish enqueue and switch out by Operation System ,
so Buffer[0]'s sequence_ is not modified , thread B do finish enqueue and do increase 
semaphore , at this monent , thread A not finish buffer[0] , thread B finish buffer[1],
thread c awaked because semaphore = 1 , so thread C will dequeue ,which try to access 
buffer[0] , which is not ready , so dequeue will return false ,  that means , thread C 
should implement like :

```
Right !!

while(1){
    sem_wait(sem1) ;
    while(1){
        if(mq.dequeue(strx))
            break ;
    }
    //doing something about strx
}

=====================================

Wrong !!

while(1){
    sem_wait(sem1) ;
    mq.dequeue(strx) ;
    //doing something about strx
}
=====================================
```

My point is , thread C awaked means there is new data enqueued , but it might be not at the position of buffer[dequeue_pos_] , so put dequeue function in endless loop will 
be helpful !!!!

Am I correct in this implement ?  I mean , there should be chance buffer[1] is filled 
before buffer[0] , and thread C awaked trying to dequeue buffer[0] failed , keep dequeue 
in endless loop won't suffer waiting forever .....because while thread A swich in by
Operation System , the buffer[0] filled finished ,thread C will break loop!!

Any suggestions,comments are appreciated !!!